# Displaying an Android Auto App on a Real Head Unit Without Play Store Listing

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-auto

This week, I developed an Android Auto app that displays specific numbers retrieved through an API. The app corresponds to the Android Auto Design Guidelines. It functions well within the AA Emulator on a PC. However, I encounter difficulties in getting it to display or work on an actual car's head unit. I understand that uploading the app to the Play Store can resolve this issue, but I'm interested in exploring alternative methods, since it's only for my personal use.

For instance, tools like AAAD (Android Auto Apps Downloader) facilitates the installation of uncertified apps on a car's system. But it only has a specific list of apps that they decide, and I can't put my own app into it.

Does anyone have experience or knowledge on how to display and operate a custom Android Auto app on a real head unit without having to list it on the Play Store? Any guidance or workarounds would be greatly appreciated